# How to edit an html file using data from a json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have the following json file

```
{
    "subject":"CSE",
    "semester":"Fall",
    "number":"219",
    "year":"2017",
    "title":"Title",
    "instructor_name":"Instructor Name",
    "instructor_home":"Instructor Home",
    "export_dir":"",
    "template_dir":"",
    "home_page_boolean":true,
    "syllabus_page_boolean":true,
    "schedule_page_boolean":true,
    "hws_page_boolean":true,
    "project_page_boolean":true,
    "banner_school_image_file":"test.jpeg",
    "left_footer_image_file":"test.jpeg",
    "right_footer_image_file":"test.jpeg"
}
```

I also have the following html file

```
/*109923473*/

<html>
    <head>
        <title>CSE 380 Home Page - Spring 2017</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/course_homepage_layout.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/sea_wolf.css">

    <!-- LINK TO OUR JQuery -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="content">

            <div id="navbar">
                <a href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/"><img class="sbu_navbar" alt="Name" src="./images/ImageLogo.png"></a>

                <a id="home_link" class="open_nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a id="syllabus_link" class="nav" href="syllabus.html">Syllabus</a>
                <a id="schedule_link" class="nav" href="schedule.html">Schedule</a>
                <a id="hws_link" class="nav" href="hws.html">HWs</a>
                <a id="projects_link" class="nav" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            </div>

            <div id="banner">
                CSE 380 - Spring 2017<br>
                Computer Game Programming
            </div>

            <div id="desc">

                <h4> ANNOUNCEMENTS:</h4>

                <p>Welcome to the CSE 380 Web site. </p>
                <br><br><br><br><br>
                <hr>
```

The json data is not in the html file. It's a separate text file called CourseDetails.json

I need to change two things.

1. Replace the various course details. So for example, in the html in the title and announcement the CSE 380 Spring 2017 part is hardcoded. I want to replace all of those details with that which is in my json file.

Is there any way to set up variables in the html file, set them to the values in the json file and then just use variable instead of hardcoded data?

So it would be like my html contains a variable like courseName and then replace every instance of courseName with CSE
so if it was

Welcome to courseName. Study a lot

it would then become

Welcome to CSE. Study a lot

2. I also have 5 boolean json data variables. Those are supposed to control which of the site pages in the navbar show up. For example, if the json file contained

   "syllabus_page_boolean":false
   "schedule_page_boolean":false

Then the navbar portion of the html file should only be

```
<div id="navbar">
    <a href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/"><img class="sbu_navbar" alt="Name" src="./images/ImageLogo.png"></a>

    <a id="home_link" class="open_nav" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a id="hws_link" class="nav" href="hws.html">HWs</a>
    <a id="projects_link" class="nav" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions
Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.

Comment: I have made a lot of attempts to solve this myself. I just didn't want to clutter up the code... I've tried making a javscript file that reads the data and appends but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

I can get you started. I do this all the time.

You can use ajax to populate the data. (I use jQuery for this). You do a jQuery ajax call which loads the JSON file and parses it. Then you use jQuery to replace the HTML in the various elements you want.

In your example, once you have parsed the data, you just put it in with:

```
$("#banner").html(<your content here>);
$("#desc").html(<your content here>);
```

There is some excellent documentation on jQuery/AJax/JSON.Check out https://www.sitepoint.com/demos/ajax/ and see the .getJSON() call which I think will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction. I'm not familiar at all with json or jquery so this is all alien to me. Those two line, do they go inside two <script> tags? And is your content here the anonymous function? And for banner, will that replace everything that is in the id banner?

Comment: OK, this is JavaScript code so yes, it goes in script tags. Assuming the JSON file doesn't change, you could put it in a document ready script.

Comment: EDITED PRIOR COMMENT -- 

OK, this is JavaScript code so yes, it goes in script tags. Assuming the JSON file doesn't change, you could put it in a document ready script.

Something along these lines.

    `<script type="text/javascript">`
 `$(document).ready(function(){`
 ` $.getJSON("whatever_the_path_to_your_file.json", `
 `  function(data){`
 `   //code in here to work with the data`
 `  });`
 `});`
 `</script>`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're learning JavaScript and/or you're new to HTML/JS technologies. I recommend you taking an introductory course at W3Schools (it's free), [direct link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

I will not code this for you since I think that you'll learn a lot if you try to implement this by yourself, but I'll give you some hints:

- To alter an HTML element you'll need to access it first. Common ways to do this are setting an ID or a Class, read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp)
- If you need to concatenate more than one value, you can do it by simply putting + between variables
- What you have to do: Load your JSON file in a JavaScript variable and then alter the HTML elements you desire, you'll need to access them so setup some IDs and/or Classes.

Have fun and good luck.

PS: I think its better to start by learning Vanilla JavaScript instead of JQuery or any other JS Framework, but this is of course up to you.